# R function not working in code

Tags: r

I'm starting to learn Timeseries forcasting in R.

I keep getting an error when running the following code (the last line is the error).

Any ideas?

> mydata = read.csv("Sample data.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",")  # read csv file
>
> Revenue_Data <- ts(mydata, frequency=12, start=c(2015,1))
>
> library("forecast")
>   library("ggplot2")
>
> logRevDataTimeSeries <- log(Revenue_Data)
>   RevForecasts <- HoltWinters(logRevDataTimeSeries)
>
> RevForecasts$SSE
>   [1] 0.141991
>
> RevForecasts2 <- forecast.HoltWinters(RevForecasts, h=48)

Error in forecast.HoltWinters(RevForecasts, h = 48) : 
  could not find function "forecast.HoltWinters"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `forecast` not `forecast.HoltWinters`. `forecast.HoltWinters` specifies that the `forecast` function can be applied to a `HoltWinters` object.

See the help page for further details: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.1/topics/forecast.HoltWinters

Comment: Thanks  this code works with your adjustment.   I'm just a bit concerned because "http://a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/timeseries.html"  is showing  the“forecast.HoltWinters()” in the Holt-Winters Exponential Smoothing example

Comment: @TimMullady The book you reference is likely out of date. The `forecast` package was recently updated on Sep 25, 2017, as seen on cran. So, I would refer to the R documentation (`?forecast.HoltWinters` or the link I mentioned in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found one simple way to get the output with holtwinnter. Try this

```
holtwinnter_fit <- holt(training_data$predictor)
```